# Failed to initialize pipeline 'Request' in policy 'CustomerContract(1.0)'

Tags: java, xml, soap-client

## I am invoking a web service from JAVA client, wsdl is created. I get the following response when I make request.

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:p="http://schemas.oblix.com/ws/2003/08/Faults">p:Client.PolicyInitializationFailure</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Failed to initialize pipeline 'Request' in policy 'CustomerContract(1.0)'</faultstring>
         <detail />
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope
```

Please help.

Comment: pls add the code where you do invoke it

Comment: @tung the issue was on the gateway of the service we are consuming. the external team managed to do a fix without providing details. Thank you.